# How can I reformat date from YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: google-sheets

Have a data set with just YYYY format which I need to reformat as YYYY-MM-DD where the day and month are always 01-01.

E.g. a cell for 1750 would be reformatted as 1750-01-01

| Entity | Code | Date | Reformatted date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 1750 | 1750-01-01 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 1751 | 1751-01-01 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 1752 | 1752-01-01 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | 1753 | 1753-01-01 |

Have tried adding day and month columns and using DATE() function to concatenate, but throws the year to 1905 for some reason (screenshot attached).

[image: screenshot of DATE() function in googlesheets]

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en. "Google Sheets uses the 1900 date system. The first date is 1/1/1900"

Comment: The earliest that Google sheets will recognize as a true date is 1/1/1900.  You can create a string that looks like a date: `=F1&"-01-01"` but you will not be able to create a true date that old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets can't handle dates prior to 1900.

If all you want to do is display the date you could use simple concatenation.

```
=F1&"-01-01"
```

That formula will return a string so you won't be able to perform any calculations/comparisons with it without further manipulation.